# Rotate a single view to landscape in a portrait locked Application in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, orientation

I have an application that uses portrait mode in the the view controllers except for one, that one page needs to be landscape only (landscape left or landscape right). How can I achieve that ?
I tried multiple solutions that say set the orientation mode for the Navigation Bar and the Application will turn but unfortunately that doesn't work for me. Also I tried manually rotating the view, it worked but when I click the text field to write something in it, the keyboard appears in the portrait mode rather than the landscape one.

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

the above code works for me but only when I allow the app to rotate in landscape and portrait both but this is not what I want because this way all the pages can turn landscape from portrait.

EDIT:

My situation here is that I have been assigned with an already made project. The guy who has made this app had been using STNavigation Manager (i'm not exaclty sure what that is) rather than self.navigationController push and pop as stuff. So shouldAutoRotate and these delegates are not working in my app. Secondly he has also disabled the navigationBar and created his own NavigationBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the landscape modes you need in the application you can use the code you are using to force the app into the landscape mode you want and then force it back to portrait before you return to the screen in which you want to be portrait.

I found the best way is to create a subclass of UINavigationController that disallows rotation via

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate
```

Then in the one view i want landscape implementing the same method on the VC level returning true.

Comment: Right you are. But let me explain you my situation, I have been assigned with an already made project. The guy who has made this app had been using STNavigation Manager (i'm not exaclty sure what that is) rather that self.navigationController push and pop as stuff. So shoudAutoRotate and these delegates are not working in my app. Secondly he has also disabled the navigationBar and created his own NavigationBar.

Comment: Ah I see then I think you are not going to be able to achieve your desired otucome. You should still be able to sethe rotation property on the nav controller or implement the method on EVERY view controller returning false.

Comment: I guess i'll have to leave the keyboard in portrait mode and the view in Landscape by GAOfflineTransform because i see no other solution to this problem :\

Comment: please upvote my question if you think its a valid question so that i can atleast get enough reputation to upvote other questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIView's transform property to rotate:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);         
self.view.transform = newTransform;

}
```

Comment: I did this but as I said in the question that this rotates the screen but when clicking the textfield to write in it, the keyboard appears in the portrait mode and not in the landscape.